# Width of search-bar & pager-bar : dataTables.net

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables plugin.

```
"bJQueryUI": true,
```

Everything else is fine.
But the search & pager bars (at bottom & top resp.) occupy entire page width.
How do I alter the width of these bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQueryUI the search and pager bar are included in UI components. I think you can override the CSS of jquery UI like this

```
.dataTables_wrapper .ui-toolbar{
    width: 50%;
}
```

remember that this directive must appear after loading the CSS of jQuery UI

Comment: Thanks Nicola. It worked. I also understood how to use Developer tools such as Opera Dragonfly to see the element's class, id, etc.  Then those attributes can be easily altered in a custom css.   Thanks again.   -- Vineet

Comment: @Vineet if this answer your question remeber to accept the answer

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti : this changes both the upper and footer toolbar. 

Can we have an approach where in we can only update the width of upper tool bar rather than the footer one?